# Does 'Exist' method in VBScript(QTP) declare the existence of

Tags: object, vbscript, runtime, qtp, exists

```
Browser("Online Exchange login").Page("Online Exchange login").Exist(10)
```

Following lines are not included in the source code:

My question is : Will `Exist(10)` method, in above line of code, verifies the existence of all Child Objects (if any) of `Page("Online Exchange login")` object before declaring its existence?

Answer (score 1):

No, `Exist` checks to see if there is currently a control that matches the description in the test object on which it was called. It does **not** check child objects.

[Further reading](http://h30501.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/Technical-How-QTP-identifies-Objects/ba-p/10332).

Answer (score 1):

No Exists method will check for the object on which it is called and not its child objects. In this case only the page object will be checked for existence.

```
Browser("Online Exchange login").Page("Online Exchange login").Exist(10)
```

In this case note that QTP waits for 
10 sec + Browser Sync Time